# Spring MVC issues with javax.validation

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, neo4j, spring-data

I wanted to create a Web-App that would use neo4j with Spring Data. I'm using Maven to handle the dependencies and building, and I'm having trouble doing this because of dependencies of `spring-data-neo4j`.

When I include spring-data-neo4j, it includes `javax.validation`, but when this is included, I have issues using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` to pick up my @Controller and @RequestMapping annotations, which causes this issue:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.validation.ValidationException: Unable to find a default provider
```

If I exclude `javax.validation` as a dependency from `spring-data-neo4j`, I get validator errors when I attempt to access `Neo4jTemplate`:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate org.neuralsandbox.controllers.IndexController.neo4jTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/validation/Validator
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: We're gonna make the validation dependency optional but it is more tricky that I thought.

Comment: Thank you for responding, My resolution was to add the Hibernate Validator, and everything worked then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible option, especially when you actually need `javax.validation` functionality, is to add an implementation of `javax.validation` (such as Hibernate Validator) to the classpath.

If you don't need `javax.validation`, you should be able to suppress this error by creating a dummy `org.springframework.validation.Validator` and configuring it as `<mvc:annotation-driver validator = "..." />`.

Comment: Well *I* don't need `javax.validation`, but `spring-data-neo4j` does, but I might go with your solution of including `javax.validation` and then just rolling my own `Validator` for the `<mvc:annotation-driver>`

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be a runtime dependency to the validation-api. it solved my problem by simple add the following runtime dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope this fixes your problem too.

Comment: You have no idea how much this just pulled my behind off the fire. Thank you.